# 403 Forbidden error from specific htaccess Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I am using `.htaccess`' `RewriteRule` to redirect a url to the proper page for a client, everything works fine, except for Rewriting the word catalogue! I get a 403 forbidden error.

This is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^catalogue$ /catalogue.php
</IfModule>
```

This results in this:

[image]

Now, what is driving me crazy is, if i switch the code to `RewriteRule ^catalog$ /catalogue.php` or `RewriteRule ^cataloguee$ /catalogue.php` and browse to the respective url, the page displays without the error.

Any ideas why this is occuring?

Comment: What if you put `Options -MultiViews` in the beginning of your `.htaccess`?

Comment: check the access/error logs to see WHY access is denied. And if need be, you can turn on the rewrite debug log to see if the rewrite is screwing up somewhere.

Comment: @zerkms no change trying that

Comment: @JimmyBanks: what url do you actually request? Does `/catalogue.php` request return 200? What is in access/error logs (from MarcB question)

Comment: @zerkms @Marc B Browsing to `/catalogue.php` is working properly with a request return 200.  No error logs seem to be appearing and error logs are on which is confusing me, ill check more configurations to see whats up with that.

Comment: Its also redirecting itself from `/catalogue` to `/catalogue/`, that i dont understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what's happening is some kind of `DirectorySlash` functionality is kicking in (adds a trailing slash when it thinks you're trying to access a directory). It's probably better not to turn that off so just match against the URI with the trailing slash:

```
 RewriteRule ^catalogue/?$ /catalogue.php [L]
```